# Data from two tables in MySql into Android app

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql

I am trying to list data from Employee table and then check if the employee listed is also in the Status table. Right now I got the listview to work but I can't seem to figure out how to connect to the Status table to see if that Employee exist using his UserID field (which is in both tables).

I am doing the following in Android:

Connection:

```
package dbtesting.example.com.testexternaldb;

        import android.util.Log;
        import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
        import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
        import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
        import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
        import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
        import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
        import org.json.JSONArray;
        import org.json.JSONException;

        import java.io.IOException;

public class ApiConnector {


    public JSONArray GetAllCustomers()
    {
        // URL for getting all customers


        String url = "http://loguru.com/Android/getAllCustomers.php";

        // Get HttpResponse Object from url.
        // Get HttpEntity from Http Response Object

        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;

        try
        {

            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = LoginPage.httpclient.execute(httpGet);

            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();



        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

            // Signals error in http protocol
            e.printStackTrace();

            //Log Errors Here



        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        // Convert HttpEntity into JSON Array
        JSONArray jsonArray = null;

        if (httpEntity != null) {
            try {
                String entityResponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

                Log.e("Entity Response  : ", entityResponse);

                jsonArray = new JSONArray(entityResponse);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return jsonArray;


    }


}
```

Main Android code

```
public class GetAllCustomerListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private JSONArray dataArray;
    private Activity activity;


    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public GetAllCustomerListViewAdapter(JSONArray jsonArray, Activity a) {

        this.dataArray = jsonArray;
        this.activity = a;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.dataArray.length();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ListCell cell;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.get_all_customer_list_view_cell, null);
            cell = new ListCell();

            cell.FullName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.customer_full_name);
            cell.Status = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.employee_status);

            cell.scan = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scan_status);

            convertView.setTag(cell);
        } else {
            cell = (ListCell) convertView.getTag();
        }

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = this.dataArray.getJSONObject(position);
            cell.Status.setText(jsonObject.getString("Status"));
            cell.FullName.setText(jsonObject.getString("Emp_F_Name") + " " + jsonObject.getString("Emp_L_Name"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ListCell {
        private TextView FullName;
        private TextView Status;

        private ImageView scan;
    }
}
```

Where my PHP code is as follows:

```
  <?php

    $con = $con = mysql_connect("URL","user","pass");

    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }
    mysql_select_db("project_nfc", $con);

    session_start();

    if (isset($_SESSION['group_id'])) {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Employee where Tag_ID!='".$_SESSION['tag_id']."' AND Group_ID='".$_SESSION['group_id']."'");

        }else{
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Employee");
        }

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
      {
        $output[]=$row;
      }

    print(json_encode($output));

    mysql_close($con);


    ?>
```

I am retrieving data from Employee table but I also want to get data from another table called Status, how can I do so? Do I need another PHP file? Can I do this in the same JSONArray?

For example my code right now retrieves the status, Emp_F_Name and Emp_L_Name from Employee but I need to also retrieve the status from EmpStatus table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use arbitrary data structures. JSON itself won't care, it'll encode pretty much any data structure you care to generate:

```
$data = array();
$data['status'] = ... data from status table query here
$data['employee'] = ... data from employee data here 

echo json_encode($data);
```

It'll just mean a bit more handling in your java-side code to work with this "new" structure.

Comment: not sure I follow, its just too confusing at this stage :)

Comment: treat json like a grocery bag. you can put in bread, pickles, fruit, blah blah. each of those is labelled in its own package and gets stuffed into the grocery bag. your android-side code unpacks the bag and then pulls out the fruit and passes those to whatever wanted fruit, unpacks the pickles, pass it to the pregnant part of your code, blah blah blah

Comment: right but my PHP side only brings data from one sql statement which is connected to one table

Comment: yes, which is what my sample showed. run multiple bits of code to fetch whatever bits of data you want, then stuff each bit of data into its own section of your eventual json response.

Comment: Is there an example I can look at? Basically what I want to do is just check if the employee fetched from Employee table is actually listed in the Status table, so not sure if its retrieving data.